# Is our "Great Comments" counted somewhere in SO in our profile?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, stack-overflow

I used to see the great comment for most of the question

people may like and appreciate it as great comment.

Is it counted  anywhere in SO just like up votes.

Is great comment is just an appreciation!!

Is there anyway i can the list and view my  "Great Comments"

I think showing a count of great comments will be good thought!!

Comment: Another example of why [Block migration if user is suspended/question-blocked at destination](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102293/block-migration-if-user-is-suspended-question-blocked-at-destination) should be implemented.

Answer (score 3):

Not directly.  You can certainly go back through the comments section of your profile and verify them by hand, but that's no fun.

You can query the DataExplorer (using https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/99/my-comment-score-distribution for Stack Overflow, change the target site on the main screen of http://data.stackexchange.com for one of the other SE sites) though.

Comment: what is userid ? for you is it jonsca Error: Invalid column name 'jonsca'. will it work for open id .. our gmail accountError: The multi-part identifier "##$$$@$$$%l.com" could not be bound.Am asking a feature . you giving me query!!!

Comment: @zod There is no feature for what you are asking.  Sorry, perhaps the 99 is unique to me.  Go to http://data.stackexchange.com, go to the upper right and login using your OpenID (the same one you use to access Stack Overflow), click on the Stack Overflow logo, and that query is on the first page.

Comment: @zod To get the userID, go to your SO profile, and it will be a 6 digit number in the search box in the upper right hand corner (it's usually filled in when you log into data.stackexchange.  One other thing to note is that the data on the explorer can be up to a month and change old, so it won't reflect your current accomplishments.

Comment: @jonsca..thanks for the info.am able to find the count  But we cant find what was the comment or for which question. Thats why i ask it as a feature request

Comment: @zod http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/163/my-comment-score-distribution will tell you the score and the post and the comment.  I'm not trying to avoid that you have made a feature request, but I'm in no position to decide upon such things.  You said `'Is there anyway i can the list and view my "Great Comments"'`, so I'm offering you a solution that works for the time being.

Comment: @jonsca thanks again . But who know these queries?  is there any way i can see the tables and columns of SO !!!

Comment: Oh This data explorer is for that ONly ..hmmm !!!

Comment: @zod I'm not a wizard on that site yet, I've mainly used queries that other people have written.  Seems to me you can get access to anything that they've migrated there.

Comment: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new

Comment: I made a similar query a while ago that lists the scores *and* the content of comments — at least the ones qualifying for the Pundit badge anyway (score of 5 or more). http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/540/whats-my-pundit-badge-progress